# HTTPS via cURL resposta JSON

Tags: php, api, libcurl

Estou tentando trazer o retorno da seguinte página com o cURL.

https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search/

Como faço isso, sendo o protocolo HTTPS?

Comment: `curl https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search/`?

Comment: Pela tag php, deve ser um método para realizar um request utilizando a API do cURL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
//$url = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLB/search/';
$url = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLB/search?category=MLB1648';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cacert.pem');

$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $output;
```

O arquivo `cacert.pem` deve ser baixado no endereço http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem e colocado na mesma pasta onde fica o script acima.

**OBS.: Quando usar a API do Mercado Livre, especifique MLB para buscar dados na versão brasileira do site. MLA se refere à versão argentina.**

---

É possível também criar uma função para facilitar um pouco:

```
<?php

function get($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cacert.pem');

    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $output;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Obtém produtos da categoria "Informática"
echo get('https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLB/search?category=MLB1648');

// Obtém as categorias do site;
echo get('https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLB/categories');

// Faz uma busca com a palavra-chave "pendrive"
echo get('https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLB/search?q=pendrive');
```

---

## Ver também:

- [Biblioteca cURL PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.curl.php)
- [Documentação da API do Mercado Livre](http://developers.mercadolibre.com/first-step/)

Comment: Gabriel, deu certo com esse certificado. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Vlw mesmo.

Comment: De nada. Estamos aqui para ensinar e aprender uns com os outros.

Comment: mais uma opção, que define a versão do SSL:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);

Comment: Esse arquivo cacert.pem é seguro?? E que site hacker é esse http://curl.haxx.se ?? Sinceramente tomem bastante cuidado, o certo é o arquivo PEM ser gerado no próprio servidor, um para cada domínio!!